# Dynamically cover 2 divs with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs that I need a shade over after a user action. The divs are just two divs next to each other:

```
<div class="bought">content</div>
<div class="class2">content</div>
```

Here is the CSS which is made visible via jQuery:

```
#view-hint .body > .img .bought {
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:2;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

When the event fires this is what it looks like:

[image]

That bottom white area needs to be covered dynamically as well.

The approach I thought to take was to wrap both div's in another div but it breaks the look of everything. So I tried to make the top div longer based off size but it's still not perfect...

```
            var originalHeight = $('.bought').height();
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            if (windowWidth < 710) {
                $('.bought').css('height', originalHeight * 0.6);
            } else if (windowWidth > 710 && windowWidth < 1000) {
                $('.bought').css('height', originalHeight * 0.698);
            } else if (windowWidth > 1000 && windowWidth < 1300) {
                $('.bought').css('height', originalHeight * 0.699);
            } else if (windowWidth > 1300 && windowWidth < 1600) {
                $('.bought').css('height', originalHeight * 0.865);
            } else if (windowWidth > 1600 && windowWidth < 2000) {
                $('.bought').css('height', originalHeight * 1.035);
            } else {
                $('.bought').css('height', "662px");
            }
```

This mostly works for all size screens, but if you change the zoom it still causes issues.

How can I make it where both of these divs are covered by the CSS dynamically?

Edit:

Here is the full HTML with an added wrapper and an image that results:

```
                <div id="test123">
                    <div class="bought">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="body">
                                    <?php if(Request::is('user/*')) { ?>
                                        <div id="boughtquestion">Did you buy this for <?php echo $user->firstName ?>?</div>
                                        <div class="options">
                                            <!-- <a id="boughtyes" class="cbutton whiteonpurple" onclick="markPurchased(event)">Yes</a> -->
                                            <a id="boughtyes" class="cbutton whiteonpurple">Yes</a>
                                            <a id="boughtno" class="cbutton whiteonpurple">No</a>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                        <div>Bought?</div>
                                        <p>Click here to send hinters a message to let them know.<br />And yes, it can still be a surprise!</p>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="markedaspurchased">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div  class="body">
                                    <div id="markedpurchased">Marked as Purchased</div>
                                    <p id="markedmessage">Marking as purchased prevents duplicate gift giving. Dont worry <?php echo $user->firstName ?> doesn't get notified but you can let <?php echo ($user->gender == 'female' ? 'him' : 'her') ?> know by sending a message!</p>
                                    <p><a id="sendmessagebutton" class="cbutton whiteonpurple purchasebutton">Send message to let them know</a></p>
                                    <p><a id="anonymousbutton" class="cbutton whiteonpurple purchasebutton">Send anonymous message</a></p>
                                    <p><a id="secretbutton" class="cbutton whiteonpurple purchasebutton">Keep it a secret</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>

            <p class="description"></info-coverp>

            <div class="options">
                <a class="buy cbutton whiteonpurple" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                <a class="hint cbutton whiteonblack" target="_blank">Hint</a>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <div class="bar"></div>
                <div class="rehints">10 REHINTS</div>
                <div class="hinter">
                    <div class="picture monophoto">
                        <div class="text">BO</div>
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url();" onclick=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="one">Hinted by:</div>
                        <div class="two"><a href=""></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="partnertext">Partnered Hint</div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: We'd really need a *brief* demo...a wrapper would be simplest but without knowing why it " *it breaks the look of everything"* it's hard to be more helpful.

Comment: How can I provide a demo? I am coming from a C# background.

Comment: Seems like you are doing much work than is necessary. If you want to wrap the divs you want to cover in a parent div modify your CSS to account for that div so it doesn't break the look of anything. Or insert the second div after the previous divs so its not wrapping and is just a sibling and position it to cover them.

Comment: Put *just enough* HTML & CSS into either JSfiddle,net demo or a Stack Snippet to demo the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/no45y0dh/

Comment: So I need the 2nd div to have the same shading without wrapping it in a div when it is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Jquery, why not give the divs a separate class and then use `.wrapAll` to create a wrapper...then position the overlay on top of that.

```js
$(".wrapped").wrapAll('<div class="overlay" />');
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.overlay::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapped bought">content 1</div>
<div class="wrapped class2">content 2</div>
```